# Triangle Inequality Theorem

Tags: vectors, geometry

I'm trying to understand the triangle inequality theorem and part of proof contains $$2\textrm{Re}(\left<a|b\right>) \leqq  2\left|\left<a|b\right>\right|.$$ Can someone show me how this is so?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

The result of the inner product $\left<a|b\right>$ is a complex number, so let's write it as $c+id$.
$$\textrm{Re}(c+id) = c$$
$$\left|c+id\right| = \sqrt{c^2 + d^2}$$